# purrr::pmap() output incompatible with what ggplot::aes() expects

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, purrr

## Problem: `purrr::pmap()` output incompatible with `ggplot::aes()`

The following *reprex* boils down to a single question, **is there anyway we can use the quoted variable names inside `ggplot2::aes()` instead of the plain text names**? Example: we typically use `ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cyl))` , how to make `aes()` work normally with `ggplot(mpg, aes("displ", "cyl"))` ?

If you understood my question, the remainder of this *reprex* really adds no information. However, I added it to draw the full picture of the problem.

---

More details: I want to use *purrr* functions to create a bunch of routinely exploratory data analysis plots effortlessly. The problem is, `purrr::pmap()` results the string-quoted name of the variables, which `ggplot::aes()` doesn't understand. As far as I'm concerned, the functions `cat()` and `as.name()` can take the string-quoted variable name and return it in the very typical way that `aes()` understands; unquoted. However, neither of them worked. The following reprex reproduces the problem. I commented the code to spare you the pain of figuring out what the code does.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Divide the classes of variables into numeric and non-numeric. Goal: place a combination of numeric variables on the axes wwhile encoding a non-numeric variable.
mpg_numeric <- map_lgl(.x = seq_along(mpg), .f = ~ mpg[[.x]] %>% class() %in% c("numeric","integer"))
mpg_factor <- map_lgl(.x = seq_along(mpg), .f = ~ mpg[[.x]] %>% class() %in% c("factor","character"))

# create all possible combinations of the variables
eda_routine_combinations <- expand_grid(num_1 = mpg[mpg_numeric] %>% names(), 
                                        num_2 = mpg[mpg_numeric] %>% names(), 
                                        fct   = mpg[mpg_factor] %>% names()) %>% 
  filter(num_1 != num_2) %>%  slice_head(n = 2) # for simplicity, keep only the first 2 combinations

# use purrr::pmap() to create all the plots we want in a single call
pmap(.l = list(eda_routine_combinations$num_1, 
               eda_routine_combinations$num_2,
               eda_routine_combinations$fct) ,  
     .f = ~ mpg %>%
  ggplot(aes(..1 , ..2, col = ..3)) + 
  geom_point() )
```

Next we pinpoint the problem using a typical *ggplot2* call.

this is what we want `purrr::pmap()` to create in its iterations:

```
mpg %>%  
  ggplot(aes(displ , cyl, fill = drv)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

However, this is `purrr::pmap()` renders; quoted variable names:

```
mpg %>% 
  ggplot(aes("displ" , "cyl", fill = "drv")) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

---

## Failing attempts

Using `cat()` to transform the quoted variable names from `pmap()` into unquoted form for `aes()` to understand fails.

```
mpg %>%  
  ggplot(aes(cat("displ") , cat("cyl"), fill = cat("drv"))) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

Using `as.name()` to transform the quoted variable names from `pmap()` into unquoted form for `aes()` to understand fails.

```
mpg %>%  
  ggplot(aes(as.name("displ") , as.name("cyl"), fill = as.name("drv"))) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

---

## Bottom line

Is there a way to make `ggplot(aes("quoted_var_name"))` work properly?

Comment: Try with the `rlang::.data` pronoun, i.e. `aes(.data[["quoted_var_name"]])`. See e.g. https://fishandwhistle.net/slides/rstudioconf2020/#7

Comment: Works exactly as expected! Thanks a lot for your help.

Side question: do you encourage the approach described above for routine EDA in small- to medium-sized datasets?

Comment: Why not? If you do that quite often then I would say this is absolutely fine, especially if you put your code inside a function to reuse your code. Still, there are already some packages to do EDA which may be worthwhile to have a look at like `EDA` or `DataExplorer`. That may even be helpful if you want to write your own function. That's what I do quite often. Trying to learn from others.

Comment: Alternatively, you can also use `aes_string(...)` in place of `aes(...)`.  Both cannot be used for a single geom or global `mapping=` argument; however, you can use both if you do some clever organizing.  For example: `ggplot(aes(x=...), aes_string(y="...")) + geom_point()` doesn't work, but this does:  `ggplot(aes(x=...)) + geom_point(aes_string(y="..."))`.

Comment: The R community is really awesome! Thanks guys for your responses. Combining your answers with the ones I got from asking on [Rstudio community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/purrr-pmap-output-incompatible-with-ggplot-aes/123121), there are 3 possible ways to successfully combine _purrr_ functional programming tools with _ggplot_ aesthetic mappings:

 1. Use `ggplot::aes_string()` instead of the regular `aes()`
 2. Use _rlang_'s tidyeval: wrap `aes()` like this `.data[[aes()]]`
 3. Use _rlang_'s `!!` operator inside `aes()` like this `aes(x = !!sym(..1), y = !!sym(..2))`

Comment: What _rlang_ sources you guys recommend a beginner like me to start with? It seems like a hugely important package and I'm shocked I haven't come across it in any of the texts I read. Your suggestion are most appreciated.